# Are there other interesting sequences of natural numbers besides the Primes with no known efficiently computable generating formula?

Tags: number-theory

For the purpose of the question, I'm excluding any set that's simply generated from the Primes with set operations, such as the set of composites or a subset of Primes, or Primes with some algebraic operations on them, such as $A \cdot p + B$ with $A, B$ natural numbers.

"Interesting" is open to interpretation, but a set of numbers that is used in and important to branches of math would help. (i.e. A purely random list of numbers is not what I'm looking for.)

Comment: Cf. [lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number)

Comment: I suspect that what you mean is generating formula "in closed form", but "efficiently computable" is out of place here. Primes are efficiently computable by a simple algorithm, whether we choose to call it a "formula" or not: take each natural number in sequence and apply a primality test (trial division, or something more sophisticated), keep those that pass. [The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) is full of sequences with no explicit formulas, those are an exception. [Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) are the oldest example.

Comment: John Littlewood proved that both $A=\{n\in \Bbb N: \pi(n)>li(n)\}$ and $B=\{n\in \Bbb N: \pi(n)<li(n)\}$ are both infinite. But before you try to compute $A$ or $B,$ see    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number